# Buttons from Base Class are Changing positions

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-4.0, windows-forms-designer

I've a base form class designed like that
[image]
At the bottom I put a docked-bottom panel and inside this panel I put two buttons. Also I set Anchor's property of these buttons to "**Top, Right**"
Also I've set Form's AutoScaleMode to **None**

On my application I inherited this base form and I don't know what is happening. My buttons go to the middle of my panel. If I set it again to the left and maybe rebuild my BaseForm it goes to the middle again.
[image]

Comment: @Saeid87 it's not about code. It's about design-time. I don't know which part of the code to show.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen this happen when controls in a base form have the `protected` modifier. That means that an inherited form can set the controls' properties (like `Location`) itself. BUt why it does it this way, I don't know.

When Winforms turned into an old lady, I stopped fighting her idiosyncrasies, just tried to work around them (as you do with old ladies). In your case I would use a `FlowLayoutPanel` in stead of a regular `Panel` and set its `FlowDirection = FlowDirection.RightToLeft`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried checking to make sure in the panel_resize event there isn't any code that manually relocates buttons?

In some of the code I inherited, there is a lot of this :

```
panel_resize(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    int buttonWidth = btnSubmit.Width + btnCancel.Width + 5; // 5 is buffer between 
    int leftOffset = (panel.Width - buttonWidth ) / 2 ; 

    btnSubmit.Left = leftOffset; 
    btnCancel.Left = btnSubmit.Right + 5; // Buffer 
}
```

This manually centers buttons during resize event ( you can do this differently, but that's what they did.)  And means the design time looks different than the actual run time.